# How to find all interactive commands in a shell script using java?

Tags: java, string, bash, lambda, find

I want to write a java function, that will scan a bash file and find if there are any commands that require user input. I know that there is a command `read`, designed to capture user input and I think that it is the only one.

I wrote a Validator class that takes a script (simple class that just loads a content of a script to a String variable using `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))`).

Here is my Validator class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Validator {

    Script script;

    String[] interactiveCommands = {"read"};

    public Validator(Script script) {
        this.script = script;
    }

    public void validateInteractiveCommands() {
        for (String string : interactiveCommands) {
            streamService(string);
        }
    }

    private void streamService(String string) {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(script.getPath()))) {
            stream.filter(lines -> lines.startsWith(string))
                    .forEach(this::printFound);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printFound(String string) {
        System.out.println("Found an interactive command: " + string);
    }

}
```

But in this case I only capture read when it is at the beggining of a line.
And in this case:

```
if true ; then
    read a
fi
```

it fails to capture read because of 4 spaces.
Is there any simple way that I can handle it using stream or lambdas? Or should I switch to regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I know that there is a command read, designed to capture user input and I think that it is the only one."

In fact, it is impossible to tell if a command in a shell script is going to capture user input.   Here are some examples:

```
  rm -i *
  cat > file
```

Indeed, it is (in general) impossible to tell which commands *might* be executed by a shell script.  For example:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  echo running "$@"
  "$@"
```

Comment: Indeed You are right. I did not think about it earlier. So it seems that the only way to assume that the script will run in a non-interactive mode is closing the stdin right?

Comment: Even that is not sufficient.  A program can (attempt to) open "/dev/tty" and read from there.